# How can I work with array result from @file

Tags: php, arrays, string, file

```
$result = @file("somefileurl.php");
```

When I do

```
echo $result;
```

***Nothing was displayed.***

When I do

```
echo $result[0];
```

it displays:

> array(2) {

When I do

```
echo $result[1];
```

it displays:

> ["column1"]=>

When I do

```
echo $result[2];
```

it displays:

> string(11) "080xxx"

And when I do

```
var_dump($result);
```

It diaplays

> array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "array(2) { " [1]=> string(16) " ["column1"]=> " [2]=> string(27) " string(11) "080xxx" " [3]=> string(16) " ["column4"]=> " [4]=> string(36) " string(20) "example@email.com" " [5]=> string(2) "} " }

Please, How can I get the values of the result to work with?

Which suppose to be two (2):

1. 080xxx
2. example@email.com

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? If you want to include a file in php you use `include` or `require`.  Trying to parse a PHP file with `file` is a bad idea IMHO. Also using `@` before the function name is a bad idea because it suppresses errors.

Comment: What i'm trying to accomplish:
On the file I called; it got two values from mysql db table, on a row. & echo them.
I want to get those values into my code, & work with them.

Comment: you need to use `include` or `require`. `file()` is for reading a data file. See @splash58's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose `file.php` contains:

```
<?php
function get_from_db() {
  //some lines with code
  $data = $array(1, 2);
  return ($data);
}
```

then in `main` php file:

```
require "file.php";
$result = get_from_db(); // result now is array (1,2)
```